# Trying to identify the names of and how to replace Ikea parts

Tags: hardware

I'm trying to put together an old Ikea table as an extra desk on which to work due to Covid related work from home. It is missing one of the four sets of threaded rods, washer and bolts that it needs. Plus it is missing the piece that sits inside the table leg in which the threaded rod secures itself. I'm looking for the name of this piece, and if possible, how to get a replacement for the whole set. I got a washer, nut and threaded rod at the hardware store, but don't really know how to go about getting the other piece as I can't even search for it without a name. See attached pics.[image: whole set]

[image: unknown piece]

Comment: They're probably proprietary parts designed and built for IKEA. I'd email them with your photos. The instructions in the kit probably mention part names and numbers also.

Comment: You may have some luck in the furniture parts drawers in the hardware aisle at the home improvement store.  Or furniture parts dealers online.

Comment: Okay, I'll try their help line. I tried the hardware store already. No luck with the second pictured thingy :(

Comment: Now's probably not a good time, and it's a bit of a crap shoot anyways, but IKEA stores typically have a bin of odd parts in their As-Is section.   If you know what you are looking for, can rummage around in that for awhile.

Comment: "Cross dowel"...

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That part is commonly known as a cross dowel. If you buy everything at once, you should be able to match thread diameter and pitch. (Your existing bolt/nut might be metric or imperial.)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! And yes, it is metric